# How do I get image URL that belongs to an article using PHP or XML?

Tags: php, xml

Retrieving image URL's from any given URL is something I know how to do. However when loading a webpage there are a dozen of src='someimg.jpg' .. How do I know which image belongs to a certain article? If I have a link to a direct article..

Example:

http://edition.cnn.com/2014/04/21/world/asia/ferry-vice-principal-funeral/index.html?hpt=hp_c1

one of the first img src =

```
<img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.element/img/3.0/global/header/intl/hdr-globe-east.gif" width="190" height="82" alt="CNN">
```

while I want to fetch :

```
<img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/140421123555-south-korea-ferry-school-vigil-story-top.jpg" alt="Danwon High School students and members of the public held a vigil for the missing ferry passengers on Sunday." border="0" height="360" width="640">
```

I just gave an example from CNN, but this could have been any other site.

Comment: You can't, unless that particular web page has a attribute in img tag which can be related to a article Id or something.

Comment: then I wonder, how does feedly, or google reader (RIP) import images that are related to articles